# I am finding an error whenever I try to save

Tags: magento

I am getting the below error:

```
Step 2 - 0.043828010559082
Step 2.1 - 0.058902978897095
Step 5 - 0.060534954071045
Step 6 - 0.070144891738892
Step 7 - 0.070178031921387
[0] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:420 Orange_Productworkflow_Adminhtml_ProductworkflowController->productSaveAction()
[1] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:253 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('productSave')
[2] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:176 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)
[3] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:340 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
[4] app/Mage.php:627 Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
[5] app/Mage.php:627 Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /var/www/site-carousels/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 288
Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/site-carousels/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Session.php on line 88
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Fixing the Allowed memory size exhausted error](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php-troubleshooting/allowed-memory-size-exausted)

Open php.ini file and update.

```
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
```

Or

Edit the .htaccess file in the magento root directory. add/update

```
## adjust memory limit
php_value memory_limit 756M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 7200
```